# Cursor visibility issue in ios7

Tags: ios7, uitextfield, text-cursor

Simply creating a `UITextField` in `ios7` `SDK` but when I enter some input, text is shown  `UItextField` but cursor isn't.

Any clue about what can be the problem?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Change the tintColor of the UITextField with a cursor

```
  [mobileTextField setTintColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
```

if you are use the XIb please set the tin color of UITextField

[image]

Note :- This is working on IOS 7+

Comment: This worked, but I still don't understand why the default tint setting doesn't work.

Comment: Every day I hate Apple a little bit more for providing such a SDK... Much more fun doing Android apps. Thanks for this anyway!

Comment: @bickster the issue is when you set the tint color to clear color or white color for your main view. Try changing that first. Then the textfields will be changed as well.

Answer (score 4):

As @Deepesh said, it's a matter of choosing the proper tint color. However it was not enough in my case since I am creating the UITextField programmatically and for some reason this setting is ignored.

```
- (UITextField *)textfieldPhotoTitle
{
    if (_textfieldPhotoTitle) {
        return _textfieldPhotoTitle;
    }

    _textfieldPhotoTitle = [[UITextField alloc] init];
    _textfieldPhotoTitle.placeholder = NSLocalizedString(@"PHOTO_UPLOAD_PHOTO_TITLE_PLACEHOLDER", @"");
    _textfieldPhotoTitle.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeASCIICapable;
    _textfieldPhotoTitle.layoutMinSize = CGSizeMake(0, 40);
    _textfieldPhotoTitle.layoutInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(11, 15, 9, 0);
    _textfieldPhotoTitle.tintColor = UIColor.blueColor; // IGNORED. NOT WORKING!!
    _textfieldPhotoTitle.delegate = self;

    return _textfieldPhotoTitle;
}
```

On the other hand, setting the color inside the textFieldDidBeginEditing did solve the issue:

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    textField.tintColor = UIColor.blueColor;
}
```

Working in iOS8.

Comment: Thank you **textField.tintColor = UIColor.blueColor;** works well.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is related to the `tintColor` of the `UITextField`.

The problem can be solved by setting the tintColor of the mainView holding the `UITextField` to `default`. Since this will affect all subviews in XCode 7.
Anyway this solved my problem and working fine from ios 7 and above.

Answer (score 0):

Same issue coming for me when I had using UITextField. The scenario is when ever tapped on textfield, immediately remove the same view.

So, this issue resolved when I have used [view endEditing:YES];

Hope this will help you.