# Syntax highlighting with attributed strings on UITextView

Tags: ios, uitextview, syntax-highlighting, nsattributedstring

There is an excellent project to add syntax highlighting and line numbers to your project: https://github.com/illyabusigin/CYRTextView

But it has one critical issue described here: https://github.com/illyabusigin/CYRTextView/issues/16

The project is **dead** on github. Can anybody help to fix the issue? I've tried to analyze code but didn't find it yet.

Comment: Didn't see all the code in GitHub, but I faced an issue similar I guess: The issue is that a some point, since you do a `[yourCustomTextView setText:ZzZ]` (or `setAttributedText:`), it causes the scroll to top. And I saw an issue with `scrollRectToVisible:animated`, if `animated` parameter was `FALSE`, then it didn't scroll. Didn't had time to find out a solution (personal project). So the only way was to set the `animated` to `TRUE` but there is indeed the effect.

Comment: Larme, there is no `scrollRectToVisible:animated` call on the code. The issue happens only on **the last empty** line.

Comment: Maybe it's because of `handleTextViewDidChangeNotification:` method in `CRTextView`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is described and fixed here: [iOS 7.1 UITextView still not scrolling to cursor/caret after new line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22315755/ios-7-1-uitextview-still-not-scrolling-to-cursor-caret-after-new-line/24108958#24108958)

```
#define SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(v) ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:v options:NSNumericSearch] != NSOrderedAscending)
#define is_iOS7 SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"7.0")
#define is_iOS8 SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"8.0")
@implementation CYRTextView {
    ...old code...
    BOOL settingText;
}

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(handleTextViewDidChangeNotification:) name:UITextViewTextDidChangeNotification object:self];
}

- (void)scrollToCaretInTextView:(UITextView *)textView animated:(BOOL)animated {
    CGRect rect = [textView caretRectForPosition:textView.selectedTextRange.end];
    rect.size.height += textView.textContainerInset.bottom;
    [textView scrollRectToVisible:rect animated:animated];
}

- (void)handleTextViewDidChangeNotification:(NSNotification *)notification {
    if (notification.object == self && is_iOS7 && !is_iOS8 && !settingText) {
        UITextView *textView = self;
        if ([textView.text hasSuffix:@"\n"]) {
            [CATransaction setCompletionBlock:^{
                [self scrollToCaretInTextView:textView animated:NO];
            }];
        } else {
            [self scrollToCaretInTextView:textView animated:NO];
        }
    }
}

- (void)setText:(NSString *)text {
    settingText = YES;
    ...old code...
    settingText = NO;
}
```